# Save mutliple form inputs of certain name into an one array with node JS (npm forms)

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, express

I've been having a rather large amount of trouble doing what I imagine to be quite a simple task. I've looked through SO and various pieces of documentation though nothing I try seems to work, thus I thought to post here.

What I'm trying to do is to handle my html form (templated through JADE), and save all data from specific inputs (name="ListContent[]") into a singular array, with one value in the array per input. I'm needing to take this approach because the number of listContent inputs is dynamic, and I do not know how many will need to be handled.

My form looks something like this:

```
<form method='post'>
    <input name='listTitle'></br>
    <input name='listDescription'></br>
    <input name='listContent[]'></br>
    <input name='listContent[]'></br>
    ...
    ...
    <input name='listContent[]'></br>
    <input name='listContent[]'></br>
    <input name='listContent[]'></br>

    <button type='button' onClick='addInput('listContent');'>
    <button type='submit'>
</form>
```

This is rendered as a form like this;
[image]

I'm able to retrieve the POSTed values of listName and listDescription as follows, though I'm at a loss for how to process the listContent and save all inputs into an array like:

"{'line 1', 'line 2', 'line 3'}"

```
var listName = form.data.listName;  // Works
var description = form.data.listDescription;  // Works 
var contentRaw = form.data.listContent;  // Just returns blank
```

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT:
I'm using npm forms (https://www.npmjs.com/package/forms) to parse /process my form data. My defined form schema is as follows:

```
var simpleNewListForm = forms.create({
    listToken: forms.fields.string({
        required:true
    }),
    listName: forms.fields.string({
        required: true
    }),
    listDescription: forms.fields.string({
        required: true
    }),
    listContent: forms.fields.array(),
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you use `listContents` while creating the form, but `listContent` while accessing it after parsing it. When I tried generating the form with the same code you showed, the input name for `listContents` is `listContents` itself in the generated HTML form.

Comment: Hey, I've tried removing the '[]' from each of the input names, however when returned listContent just comes up as 'undefined'. Thoughts?

Comment: What are you using to parse the request data ?

Comment: node npm forms : https://www.npmjs.com/package/forms

I'll update with my defined form schema. Thanks for helping me with this by the way mate.

Comment: You got it! Simple mistake costing me precious hours. That, in addition to your above suggestion marks a successful answer. Cheers!

Comment: Okay I moved it to the answer, as the previous one just helped to get into the answer.

Comment: Glad you got over the problem.